# Selecting records according to date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, comparison, timestamp

I have two tables -- we'll call them `grade` and `test` -- with info that is related by way of a key on a third table, which we'll call `student`.

If `test` contains columns `student_id`, `test_topic`, and `test_date`, and `grade` contains columns `student_id`, `grade`, and `entered_date`, I want to be able to look at a record in the `grade` table and, based on the `student_id` and `entered_date`, associate it only with the record in `test` with the same `student_id` whose date is most recent.

My current query seems to return each grade associated with all former tests, instead of only the most recent one. I can't figure out how to limit it so that it will show each grade only matched with what was the most recent test at the time the grade was entered.

I don't think I've explained this very well, so I've set up a SQL Fiddle with the example schema, some test data, and my current query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5233/5

**ETA:** To clarify: I'd like the query to report back with the grade for **each** test taken, which is deduced by way of the most recent test taken at the time the grade was entered. I've added a new variant fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5233/43 with a query that includes the test topic, which I think makes the problem a little clearer. For 'Adam' (student_id = 1) the desired result would be:

```
STUDENT_ID                 TEST_DATE                       TEST_TOPIC                      GRADE_TIME                TEST_GRADE
     1          October, 02 2013 23:08:24+0000          Medieval History          October, 02 2013 23:08:25+0000          A
     1          October, 02 2013 23:08:30+0000          Calculus                  October, 02 2013 23:08:32+0000          C
     1          October, 02 2013 23:08:43+0000          Biochemistry              October, 02 2013 23:08:44+0000          A
     1          October, 02 2013 23:08:49+0000          Advanced German           October, 02 2013 23:08:50+0000          C
```

but currently you'll see what it gives back is each grade in the grade table matched against **all** tests taken before that instead of only the most recent.

Comment: have you tried a GROUP BY student_id?

Comment: I have, though I admit that I'm having trouble understanding how GROUP BY works. Ultimately, it only seems to return one record for a given student, instead of returning one for each test they took.

Comment: are you trying to get all of the latest grades by test, per student (or a single student as you've limited on the fiddle)?

Comment: That's a good question. Ultimately, I'm wanting to build a view out of this select, so in reality I want it to be all the latest grades by test, per student, for each student, but in my testing I've just been limiting it to one student to make it easier to see if it's working as expected.

Comment: Is there one grade row corresponding to each test row? Or, can there be more than one grade for a test? Or more than one test for a grade?

Comment: There could be more than one grade per test. (Think of an online course where they allow you to submit exercises more than once.) There is only ever one test active at the time of grading.

Answer (score 2):

I would think you should have a test_id foreign key in your grade table so that you don't have to try to join on a convoluted date value that would cause you problems (i.e. what if a student takes more than one test on a given date).

That would give you a means to directly relate the grade to the test for the particular student.

Comment: I was thinking in the same thing

Comment: Admittedly part of the weakness of the example is that I'm trying to make it more generic than the problem I'm really trying to solve, alas. In any case, the schema change of making a test_id FK in the grade table isn't an option, even though I'm aware that it would be the ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The schema is off - as you probably already know. There should be a way to directly relate the grade to the test id. Otherwise, something like this will work (though I believe to be too heavy on the database and not performatic with a high number of rows on the  tables).

```
SELECT
  S.student_id,
  S.student_name AS Student,
  T.test_topic AS Topic,
  G.grade AS Grade,
  T.test_date AS `Test Date`,
  G.entered_date AS `Grade Time (debug)`
FROM
  student S, test T, grade G
WHERE
  S.student_id = G.student_id
  AND S.student_id = T.student_id
  AND G.entered_date > T.test_date
  AND T.test_date = 
  (
    SELECT MAX(T2.test_date)
    FROM test T2
    WHERE T2.student_id = T.student_id
    AND T2.test_topic = T.test_topic
  )
  AND 
  (
    G.entered_date < 
      (
        SELECT MIN(T3.test_date)
        FROM test T3
        WHERE T3.student_id = T.student_id
        AND T3.test_topic <> T.test_topic
        AND T3.test_date > T.test_date
      )
    OR NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT 1
        FROM test T4
        WHERE T4.student_id = T.student_id
        AND T4.test_topic <> T.test_topic
        AND T4.test_date > T.test_date
      )
   )
ORDER BY S.student_id, T.test_date, G.entered_date
```

The query above fetches the latest test for a topic and student and then proceeds to match the found rows with the grade for that student with the highest `entered_date` **that is lower than the next test's time** OR **for which no later test dates can be found**.

Here, have a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c069f/9/0